# MSI self heal doesn't repair shortcut on Windows XP

Tags: 64-bit, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a 32bit .NET app that uses the built-in MSI setup project in VS 2008.

It is deployed per-user using a GPO. This means it is installed on each computer the user logs on to. This way each user automatically gets the correct shortcut on their desktop.

All our workstations are Windows XP (32bit), but some of our users also log on to a terminal server (Windows Server 2008) which is 64bit. When they log on to the server and click on the shortcut, the msi installer launches (I think it's self-healing, changing the shortcut to `Program files (x86)` and they can use the application.

The problem is that when they log on to their workstation again and they click on the shortcut on their workstation, it immediately fails because the shortcut points to the `Program files (x86)` folder, wich doesn't exist on the XP machine.

I'd expect the MSI to self heal again to fix the shortcut. Can I force this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Windows Installer.

The automatic repair is performed only when Windows Installer detects a missing resource. Most likely the server machine cannot access some application files or registry entries, so it performs a repair which just happens to modifies the shortcut target. It's basically a coincidence.

Since the user account is roaming (the user can use it on multiple machines), the application should be installed in the user profile folder. Windows Installer provides [AppDataFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) for this.

Using the user profile roaming folder will allow your users to access the application files correctly from any machine.